# Extra substrate in TSA

Tags: rf, antenna, high-frequency, pcb-antenna

[image]I have designed a tapered slot antenna operating in C band on an FR4 substrate . However , despite rigorous simulations the response has shifted by nearly 1 Ghz . I was wondering if extra substrate in the TSA has caused this?[image]

Comment: Show your polar-plot response versus axis, and response versus frequency.

Comment: "on a FR4 substrate" if your design process involves "just some FR4" then these things can easily happen...

Comment: @analogsystemsrf added

Comment: what do you mean 'extra' substrate. If your analysis was rigorous, it would have included **all** the substrate that appears in the physical models, and there would not be any extra. Is your question 'why does the frequency shift when I add a load of un-modelled substrate to my antenna?'? I so, the answer is 'Duh!' FWIW FR4 is not well specified at 5GHz (to put it mildly), I would recommend you go to something like Rogers 4350.

Comment: How well formed is the beam (the polar plot of gain versus degrees)?

Comment: @Neil_UK would 185HR http://www.isola-group.com/products/185hr/ be good for C band . It does have specifications mentioned at 5Ghz

Comment: 185HR looks fine. I only mention 4350 because you can process it like FR4, and it's relatively inexpensive